# Link Click to Update Data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to click an "Archive" link in the view to call controller to update database using ajax in MVC application. My code always returns error. Please help!

View:

```
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anchorArchive" data-id="@item.id">Archive</a>
```

Controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Archive(int id)
    {
        myTable model = db.myTable.Find(id);
        db.Entry(myTable).Property("Archived").CurrentValue = true;
        db.SaveChanges();
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        return Content("Archived");
    }
```

javascript code:

```
$(function () {
var PostBackURL = '/Admin/Archive';
$(".anchorArchive").click(function () {
    // debugger;
    var $buttonClicked = $(this);
    var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: PostBackURL,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { "id": id },
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
                alert("Archived Successfully"); 
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, why you have `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`  ?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the javascript code in

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 'id': id }),
```

and controller return as

```
 return Json(new { status = "Success", message = "Success" });
```

The ajax call works now.